# Database design mapping employees to positions on a job shift

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, database-design

I'm designing a database for an employee scheduling system. Each shift has M different roles that must be filled and each of N employees is qualified for an combination of those M different roles.

The naive design is to put M boolean flags into each employee record. Does this require me to constrain the number of roles that can be supported at design time or do modern databases have a way to avoid the potentially unbounded MxN table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like:

```
Roles
  id
  name

Employee
  id
  name

Qualifications
  id
  employee_id
  role_id

Shifts
  id 
  role_id
  date
  shift_number

EmployeeShifts
  id
  shift_id
  employee_id
```

Comment: Yep, the Qualifications and EmployeeShift tables are mapping Roles to Employees and Employees to Shifts respectively. Kind of like a sparse matrix. Thanks, I was making this more complicated in my head.